# How to round up an integer by c#?

Tags: c#

I want a function to round up an integer, like this 
    11 -> 20
    12 -> 20
    31 -> 40
    39 -> 40
    50 -> 50
what can i do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: `(source + 9) / 10 * 10` in case of non-negative numbers only; `(sourse + (source > 0 ? 9 : -9)) * 10 / 10` in general case; there's a possibility of the integer overflow if `source` is close to `int.MaxValue` or `int.MinValue`

Comment: you can make a function like this: 

static int roundAsYouWant(int num){
            return num % 10 == 0 ? num : ((Convert.ToInt32(num / 10)) * 10) + 10;
        }

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var mod = (i % 10);
var result = mod > 0 ? (i + 10 - mod) : i;
```

Comment: You aren't only calculating `result`, you are also changing `i`. I guess that is an undesired side effect.

Comment: @PatrickHofman exactly, I've changed it

Comment: Well, Nitesh changed it ;) . But it will do. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've accepted his edit, because I wanted to make same edit :)